# PhpDoc show indirect extended method

Tags: php, phpdoc

We have some magic behaviour that adds additional features to class.

Right now we have lots of similar code:

```php
/**
 * @see \App\Behaviour::someMethod
 * @method mixed someMethod(string ...$params)
 *
 * @see \App\Behaviour::anotherMethod
 * @method void anotherMethod()
 */
class Foo {
    public function __call(string $method, array $params) {
        $this->behaviour->{$method}(...$params);
    }
}
```

---

Is there a way to automatically indicate this magic behaviour instead of re-writing all public methods for each class that has this feature?

E.g. (non-existing code)

```php
/**
 * @magic-call \App\Behaviour
 */
class Foo {

}
```

Comment: Maybe offtopic but: How about moving `\App\Behaviour` into a Trait instead of using `__call`?  I thing Traits are for this: adds additional features to class

Comment: Trait, base class or interfaces would be my preference, if at all possible!

Comment: @Foobar I can't actually change that behaviour into trait, because it's framework code. I know about traits usage, but need this approach documented for better IDE work